# When trying to compile the exported tex file, I get the error `Environment org undefined`

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, beamer

I use `org-beamer-export-to-latex` to export the current org file to latex. When I try to manually compile the resulting tex file using

```
latexmk -f -pdf -pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode x.tex
```

I get this error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Environment org undefined.
```

I think this is because there is a

```
\begin{org}
```

in the tex file.

This env seems to be inserted because of this snippet in org-mode:

```
#+begin_src mermaid :eval no-export :background-color transparent :wrap "org \n#+ATTR_HTML: :width 950 \n#+ATTR_LATEX: :width \\textwidth" :scale 3 :file test..nogit..pdf
graph LR
    A[Image of Bird] -->|Input To| B[Neural Network]
    B -->|Classifies As| C["Bird"]
    E[Attribution Map] -->|Major Contributors Are| D[Pixels Showing Face, Tail, …] 
    B --> E
    C --> E
#+end_src

#+results: 
#+begin_org
#+attr_html: :width 950
#+attr_latex: :width \textwidth
[[file:test..nogit..pdf]]
#+end_org
```

I am currently using `\newenvironment{org}{}{}` as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Having `:wrap org` in the header will wrap the results in a `#+begin_org...#+end_org` block and the latex exporter will translate that to `\begin{org}... \end{org`.

Try this instead:

```
#+name: mygraph
#+begin_src mermaid :eval no-export :background-color transparent :scale 3 :file test..nogit..pdf
graph LR
    A[Image of Bird] -->|Input To| B[Neural Network]
    B -->|Classifies As| C["Bird"]
    E[Attribution Map] -->|Major Contributors Are| D[Pixels Showing Face, Tail, …] 
    B --> E
    C --> E
#+end_src

#+attr_html: :width 950
#+attr_latex: :width \textwidth
#+results: mygraph
[[file:test..nogit..pdf]]
```

I presume that you tried the `:wrap org` for the side effect of inserting the `#+ATTR_...` declarations, but that is not the way to do that. What you need to do is to give your `mermaid` source block a name (`#+name: mygraph` above). Then when you run the source block, it will produce a labeled `#+results:`  block. Then you can add the `#+attr_...` declarations *before* the `#+results:`  block. You can then rerun the code block and it will *still* find the labeled `#+results:`  block to put the result under, even though the `#+attr_...` declarations separate the source block from the results block.